# SQLAlchemy using both primaryjoin and secondaryjoin with association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database for genomics. I have two tables, `Gene` and `Mutation` and I am trying to join them together. The genes are related to mutations if are on the same chromosome and their positions overlap. I tried using association table to try to connect them and get a join statement using Flask SQLAlchemy but I keep running into errors. Here is my setup:

```
class Mutation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mutation'
    mutation_index = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    chrom = Column(String(40), ForeignKey("contig.accession"))
    mutation_start = Column(Integer)
    mutation_end = Column(Integer)
    
    gene = relationship("Gene",
                        primaryjoin="and_(gene_mutations.c.gene_chrom == Mutation.chrom, "
                        "Mutation.mutation_start <= gene_mutations.c.gene_end, "
                        "gene_mutations.c.gene_start <= Mutation.mutation_end)",
                        secondary="gene_mutations", 
                        secondaryjoin="gene_mutations.c.gene_id == Gene.gene_id",
                        back_populates="mutations", viewonly=True)
class Gene(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gene'
    gene_id = Column(String(40), primary_key=True)
    chrom = Column(String(40))
    gene_start = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    gene_end = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    mutations = relationship("VCF",
                             primaryjoin="and_(Gene.accession == gene_mutations.c.mutation_chrom, "
                            "gene_mutations.c.mutation_start<= Gene.end, "
                            "Gene.start <= gene_mutations.c.mutation_end)",
                            secondary="gene_mutations",
                            secondaryjoin="gene_mutations.c.mutation_id == Mutation.variant_index",
                            back_populates="gene", viewonly=True)


gene_mutations = Table("gene_mutations", 
                       db.Model.metadata,
                       db.Column("mutation_id", ForeignKey('mutation.mutation_id')),
                       db.Column("mutation_start", ForeignKey('mutation.mutation_start')),
                       db.Column("mutation_end",  ForeignKey('mutation.mutation_end')),
                       db.Column("mutation_chrom",  ForeignKey('mutation.chrom')),
                       db.Column("gene_id", ForeignKey('gene.gene_id')),
                       db.Column("gene_start", ForeignKey('gene.start')),
                       db.Column("gene_end", ForeignKey('gene.end')),
                       db.Column("gene_chrom", ForeignKey('gene.chrom'))
                       )
```

If I have the logic setup correctly, the complicated looking `primaryjoin` should just find overlaps between the `Gene` and `Mutation`. So my logic was to connect `Mutation` to `gene_mutations` and then connect `gene_mutations` to `Gene` and vice-versa so I can join them together and filter based on different criteria. When I try to join the tables like this:

```
Mutation.query.join(gene_mutations, (gene_mutations.c.mutation_id == Mutation.mutation_index)).all()
```

I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1146 (42S02): Table 'mutations.gene_mutations' doesn't exist
```

Is this the right way to go about joining these two tables?

**EDIT:** So I launched mysql and manually added the table `gene_mutations` and that seems to have partially solved the error. Now it becomes, two question. 1) How do I make sure that `gene_mutations` table gets created everytime I run `db.create_all()`. I thought having the db.Model.metadata would create that. Second, unfortunately the query

```
result = Mutation.query.join(gene_mutations, (gene_mutations.c.vcf_id == Mutation.mutation_index))
```

comes back empty. How do I create a joined table that can map mutations to genes (many-to-many map).

Comment: Your Mutation and Gene classes each have a single-column primary key (mutation_index and gene_id, respectively), so if the sole purpose of your association table is to provide a many-to-many relationship between Mutation and Gene objects then that table should only have two ForeignKey columns. All of the other ForeignKey definitions in that table are superfluous and make your overall data model much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I see. So how do I define the logic of how the two are associated i.e. they are found in same chromosome and their positions overlap.

Comment: That would be a matter of *validation*. You would need to verify that the required conditions exist before adding the row to the association table. That could be done with client-side code, or with an SQL trigger on the association table.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was thinking about the joins in completely wrong way. I misunderstood and thought SQL was going to populate the association table for me based on the secondary join criteria I provided. Now it makes more sense.